# Sorting of a numeric vector in the ggplot graph after group by variables and pipe using facet_wrap

Tags: r

I have a code like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Calculate some means
mean_data <- group_by(df, Duration, Time.elapsed,P_R_coef, R_L_coef) %>%
  summarise(mean_A = mean(Number.of.theories.to.be.discovered, na.rm = TRUE), mean_B = mean(Number.of.published.theories.CK, na.rm = TRUE), mean_C = mean(Number.of.refuted.theories, na.rm = TRUE), mean_D = mean(Number.of.true.published.theories, na.rm = TRUE), mean_E = mean(Number.of.false.published.theories, na.rm = TRUE), mean_F = mean(Theta, na.rm = TRUE))

#Plot some means
ggplot(mean_data %>% mutate(group = paste(as.numeric(P_R_coef),as.numeric(P_R_coef),Duration, sep="-")),
  aes(Time.elapsed)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_A, colour = "Nb.T.to.be.discovered")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_B, colour = "Nb.T.published.CK")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_C, colour = "Nb.T.refuted")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_D, colour = "Nb.true.published")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_E, colour = "Nb.false.published")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_F*200, colour = "Theta")) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free", labeller = label_both)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Mean", color = "Epistemic landscape") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    "Mean", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./200, name = "Theta")
  )
```

When plotting, the ordering of the plot I get is incorrect. As can be seen in the last row of the plot, facet_wrap shows P_R_coef 10 before P_R_coef 2.

[image]

I have tried coercing numeric, integer and character vector types, but that doesn't help. My goal is that in the last row of the graph, 2 and 3 appear before 10. I appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Did you try reordering the variable `group `with the function `factor` ?

Comment: hi - manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the result of `as.numeric(x)` with `sprintf` to obtain a two-digit group head for proper ordering: `sprintf('%02.0f', as.numeric(2))` produces "02" which is then placed before "10" as desired.

On a sidenote: taking advantage of `{dplyr}`s functions can save a lot of work. E.g. calculating the mean for a selection of variables can be as concise as this:

```
mean_data <- 
    df %>%
    summarise(
        across(Number.of.theories.to.be.discovered : Theta,
               ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
               )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I add 0 floats by doing '%02.0f', the facet_wrap labels are of the type "group: 00-1.00-300", "group: 00-2.00-300", so the decimals of the variable P_R_coef are not made explicit in the labels. Thanks for the dplyr advice, I totally had forgotten about such function...